# How to calculate Content-Length for a file download within Kohana PHP?

Tags: php, header, kohana, content-length

I'm trying to send a file from within a Kohana model to the browser, but as soon as I add a Content-Length header, the file doesn't start downloading right away.

Now the problem seems to be that Kohana is already outputting buffers. An ob_clean at the begin of the script doesn't help this though. Also adding ob_get_length() to the Content-Length isn't helping since this just returns 0.
The getFileSize() function returns the right number: if I run the script outside of Kohana, it works.

I read that exit() still calls all destructors and it might be that something is outputted by Kohana afterwards, but I can't find out what exactly.

Hope someone can help me out here...

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
public function download() {
        header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()+(3600*7))." GMT\n");
        header("Content-Type: ".$this->getFileType()."\n");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",$this->getCreateTime()) . " GMT\n");
        header("Content-Length: ".($this->getFileSize()+ob_get_length()).";\n");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($this->getFileName())."\"\n\n");
        ob_end_flush();

        readfile($this->getFilePath());
        exit();
}
```

Comment: If you are using Kohana v3, don't use header("Content-Type:..."), use `$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = $this->getFileType();` if you are inside a controller.

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler way to send a file with Kohana. If you are using **Kohana 2.x** it's done like this...

```
download::force('./application/downloads/file.txt');
```

[Documentation](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/download)

If you are using **Kohana 3.x**, it is done like this...

```
$this->request->send_file('./application/downloads/file.txt');
```

[Documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Request#send_file)

Answer (score 0):

Found out I needed to call Kohana::close_buffers(FALSE) to clear Kohana's output buffer. 
It was a long search, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.1 and forward, use

```
Request::current()->response()->send_file(FILENAME);
```

Took me some digging so hopefully this helps someone

[Documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Response#send_file)